# Pasting images from the clipboard into a Stack Exchange Site (Stack Overflow, AskUbuntu, etc) doesn't work anymore on Chrome for Linux

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard

I can't paste images into Stack Overflow anymore. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (with an image from a snipping tool already in the clipboard) nothing happens. Does anyone else have this problem?

I'm on Chrome Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit) in Linux [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29).

The snipping tools I tried are Shutter and Screenshot. I get the same behavior on two computers, each running Chrome (and logged into my Chrome account, with my Chrome plugins). One computer is Ubuntu 18.04, and the other is [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)).

The problem seems to exist in the Chrome browser only. In FireFox on the same computer it works fine.

Disabling all plugins in Chrome doesn't seem to make a difference. Neither does using Incognito Mode. Any idea what could be the problem? It used to work. It's been a few months since it last worked I think.

To further confuse me, pasting images works fine from my work's stack enterprise stack overflow system on the same computer and in the same Chrome browser at https://company_name.stackenterprise.co/.

See also my question here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411266/pasting-images-from-the-clipboard-doesnt-seem-to-work-anymore-on-chrome-for-lin

Comment: What's the reason people are using for hitting the "close" button on this question?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm pretty sure this still worked last week.

By the way, i didn't notice this problem on SO, but on a different site. I am running 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I opened a Chrome bug ticket, hopefully somebody takes a look at it soon: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1246811

Comment: @jgosar, you opened a Chromium bug report. Last I checked the problem is on Chrome only, not Chromium. I'll do a check on Chromium when I get a chance.

Comment: I see, I just tried it in Chromium and it actually works, so I guess that bug report is a bit misplaced :(

Comment: I VTC'd because this is a bug report. This isn't the place for reporting bugs or asking people to repro them.

Comment: @muru, bug report for who? Stack Overflow, Ubuntu, Chrome, or someone else? Where should I post this bug report?

Comment: Bug report for SE: post on [meta]. Bug report for Ubuntu: file on Launchpad. For Chrome: their bug tracker, wherever that is. It's up to you to decide which is most suitable. The devs there will then tell you if you should file elsewhere.

Comment: @GabrielStaples It seems that this question is closed, so I can't answer it, but here is the temporary solution I got on my Chromium bug ticket:
Go to chrome://flags/#use-ozone-platform and select "Disabled"

Comment: Solved by [this answer by @jgosar here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411266/pasting-images-from-the-clipboard-doesnt-seem-to-work-anymore-on-chrome-for-lin/411569#411569).